# how to observe new values of an SignalProducer array

Tags: swift, reactive, reactive-swift

I have a `SignalProducer` that contains an array, I want to observe only new changes and not get the whole array when I observe it

I try flatMap `.latest` but it does not work

Anyone have an idea of how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single function available that does that, but you can implement this by using `combinePrevious`:

```
let change = producer.combinePrevious([]).map { (previous, current) in
  // Calculate change
  return change
}
```

How you calculate the change between the previous array and the current array, however, depends on what exactly "only new changes" means in your context.

Do you want the elements that have been added? Elements that have been removed? Are there duplicates allowed? Does the position matter and has the change to include the change in position?

If you only need the elements that have been added and have no duplicates, I suggest to use a `Set` instead of an `Array`

E.g:

```
let p = MutableProperty([1, 2, 3])

let added = p.producer.map(Set.init)
  .combinePrevious([])
  .map { (previous, current) in
    return current.subtracting(previous)
}

added.startWithValues { print($0) }

p.value = [1, 2, 3, 4]
p.value = [2, 4]
p.value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mexx I'll try that solution

Answer (score 2):

I believe `.skipRepeats()` operator does the job for you.

It will just forward the values that are not equal to its immediately proceeding value and it works for the array as well.

Just remember that your array elements should conform to `Equatable`.

```
yourProducer.skipRepeats().startWithValues {newValues in
            //do your stuff here
        }
```

This one also works well, because it filters the new values and forwards distinct values only:

```
yourProducer.combinePrevious().map({val -> [String] in
            let (prev, current) = val
            return current.filter({!prev.contains($0)})
        }).startWithValues {newValues in
            //do your stuff here
        }
```